# Setting display panel refresh rate in Android OpenGL apps ignored

Tags: android, opengl-es, sdl, frame-rate

The test device Samsung S21 can switch refresh rate between 60hz and 120hz. The developer option "show refresh rate" displays 60hz in the corner as soon as my OpenGL 3.0 app is launched. Some other apps and the Android GUI run at 120hz.

Display.getSupportedModes() returns: 120,96,60,48

Calling Surface.setFrameRate(120,1); has no effect.

**EDIT:**
This is an SDL Android app. The non-SDL NDK samples run fine.